# Calculate distance between two sets of x & y values into a new field using ArcMap Field Calculator and Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, distance, python-parser

I am a novice when it comes to python. I am working on creating a new field that has the distance between two sets of x & y values.

I've joined two tables so I have each of their x y values in the same table. I am using field calculator in ArcMap trying to format this equation and for the life of me cannot figure it out. I'm not using the codeblock, is this necessary? I have been attempting to get the results to compute for days. I've gotten a few different errors. I'm wondering if its an error stemming from the function I'm using I've looked through the forums and can't find an answer.

So far what I have is:
[image: This is the expression I am attempting to use:]

```
math.sqrt(((!x2!-!x1!)**2)-((!y2!-!y1!)**2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Your title says you're using VBScript, but the code says Python. I'd use a Python function, define dx and dy, then use `return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)`

Comment: Hey Vince, my mistake. I am using python. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Use "join field" instead of "add join" and math.hypot(x1-x2, y2-y1). This will make expression easier to type, less errors

Comment: I greatly appreciate all of your input. I am still struggling. When using field calculator, should I be defining these variables in the pre-logic script code? Or should I be able to just plug in the fields as necessary in the expression? Thanks again

Comment: No need in a block. Just replace x1,x2... by relevant !point_x!, !point_x1!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs:

[image]

```
arcpy.JoinField_management(in_data="SET_A", in_field="J_FIELD", join_table="SET_B", join_field="J_FIELD", fields="POINT_X;POINT_Y")
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table="SET_A", field_name="DISTANCE", field_type="DOUBLE", field_precision="", field_scale="", field_length="", field_alias="", field_is_nullable="NULLABLE", field_is_required="NON_REQUIRED", field_domain="")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Control:

```
arcpy.XYToLine_management(in_table="SET_A", out_featureclass="in_memory/LINES", startx_field="POINT_X", starty_field="POINT_Y", endx_field="POINT_X_1", endy_field="POINT_Y_1", line_type="GEODESIC", id_field="J_FIELD", spatial_reference="PROJCS['NZGD_2000_New_Zealand_Transverse_Mercator',GEOGCS['GCS_NZGD_2000',DATUM['D_NZGD_2000',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',1600000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',173.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-4020900 1900 1000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.002;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! I appreciate everyone's input. This worked for me. Just for clarification, could this have been done the original way I was working on it? By using the square root function?

Comment: Yes, because square root and hypot are  identical functions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!